# How to get path of the running process, with lack of user's permissions

Tags: windows, winapi

Is it possible to extract path to the process, if this process is executed by admin account from the user account? if your user account don't have permissions to this process.
CreateToolhelp32Snapshot gets list of all processes in a system, not depending on user permissions, but this snapshot contains only .exe names, without path.

Comment: I assume you're not talking about getting the path of the *current* process, right?

Comment: I removed the Delphi tag because this is really a winapi question and the presence of the Delphi tag may discourage our winapi experts.

Comment: Rob Kennedy, Not the current process, shure, but process from toolSnapshot or EnumProcesses list.

David Heffernan, thnk you

Answer (score 5):

`CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` and `Process32First`/`Next` will give you the process ID of each process. Use that ID with [`OpenProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320.aspx) to get a process handle, and then pass that handle to [`QueryFullProcessImageName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684919.aspx) (requires Windows Vista or later). When you call `OpenProcess`, request just `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` access, and you should be able to access even elevated-privilege processes.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I'l try this solution a little bit later and report about results. By the way, can I use [GetModuleFileNameEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683198(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of QueryFullProcessImageName, or anything similar for Win versions older than Vista? Need to use this function on WinXP and WinServer2003

Comment: You can try, but the permission flag required for the new API is also new, and probably the reason the new API exists at all. `GetModuleFileNameEx` requires `PROCESS_VM_READ`, which processes won't be allowed to acquire for processes with elevated privileges. The Process32First documentation says to use Module32First to get the full process name, but again, you might find you don't have enough permissions to use it on certain processes. If all the old functions already worked, then the new API function wouldn't have needed to be invented.

Comment: Both QueryFullProcessImageName and PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION access type are available in Vista win7 only( Even using win7, my rad studio 2007 doesn't understand this directives. So this solution is not suitable for me.

Comment: And what about [Access Tokens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374909(v=vs.85).aspx), I'm not acquainted with them enough, can I grant rights to user application or share privileges on admin app with help of tokens?

Comment: You can declare them yourself. You don't need Delphi's own declarations. You could use them from Delphi 2 if you wanted to. Access tokens will be a problem, though. With access tokens, you can grant access from other user accounts, so you could allow your limited account to access a privileged process it wouldn't normally have access to. But to do that, the privileged process needs to already exist, and the only thing that can grant access is something that already has access. If you already have something that can grant access, then you may as well just write your path-fetching code there.

Answer (score 0):

Spended a lot of time trying to cope with permissions. I think, in fact - it is possible to grant necessary privileges to process, to make processes of user and admin see each other and cooperate. But, I didn't find suitable solution using this method.
Exactly what i needed - synchronyze applications running under different users, and I found solution for my case - [Global mutex!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
When application is starting, it creats it's own mutex and check if there existing a simmilar process searching his mutex.

Comment: + example 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470921/how-do-you-protect-a-common-resource-using-mutexes